# How to find element based on data attr and input name that is array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html markup:

```js
//this is in ajax success result
success: function(response) {
  if(response.success) {
    $("[data-input='" + response.field + "']").parents('.file-wrapper').find("[data-item='" + response.item + "']").remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-2 director-label-file" for="director_front_passport">Front ID/Passport</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8 file-wrapper">
                                    <input type="file" name="director_front_passport[]" class="app-file valid" data-item="1" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                                    <label class="file-upload" for="director_front_passport"><span>Upload a File</span></label>
                                    <div data-input="director_front_passport" class="file-name"><span class="image_wrapper"><span data-num="0" class="image_name">Link to image.jpeg</span><span title="Remove" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-file"></span></span></div><label id="director_front_passport[]-error" class="error" for="director_front_passport[]"></label>
                                </div
```

In ajax response I have:

```js
{"success":true,"errors":false,"field":"director_front_passport","num":"0","item":"1"}
```

I want to find element with name=director_front_passport (or with data-input = director_front_passport - it's the same) and after that to find element with `data-item = response.item` which in this case = 1.

How to find it? I tried in this way.

Comment: In fact I need to find input with `data-input=director_front_passport` but also with `data-item =`. I found this input with :$("[data-input='" + response.field + "']") . But how to add condition also this field to have `data-item=1`?

Comment: I would put both conditions in selector. see this link: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/
i'll post an answer shortly

Comment: Your code works. The problem seems to be elsewhere. Look at this simplified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wmm7owqe/ Are you sure your ajax s returning JSON and not a String? Did you add the 'json' parameter to the ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead to use **parents** you may use [.closest( selector )](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

While parents gets the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector;

closest gets the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

If the returned value from ajax is a string you may convert it with **JSON.parse**

My example:

```js
$(function () {
  var response = '{"success":true,"errors":false,"field":"director_front_passport","num":"0","item":"1"}';

  $("[data-input='" + response.field + "']").closest('.file-wrapper').find("[data-item='" + response.item + "']").remove();

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 director-label-file" for="director_front_passport">Front ID/Passport</label>

    <div class="col-md-8 file-wrapper">
        <input type="file" name="director_front_passport[]" class="app-file valid" data-item="1" aria-required="true"
               aria-invalid="false">
        <label class="file-upload" for="director_front_passport"><span>Upload a File</span></label>

        <div data-input="director_front_passport" class="file-name"><span class="image_wrapper"><span data-num="0"
                                                                                                      class="image_name">Link to image.jpeg</span><span
                title="Remove" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip"
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-file"></span></span></div>
        <label id="director_front_passport[]-error" class="error" for="director_front_passport[]"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't correct. I need to find element with data-input = response.field that has data-item=response.item and after that I need to find element with class=image_name and remove it. In this case I need to remove "Link to image.jpeg" text.

Comment: @mistery_girl In order to remove "Link to image.jpeg" you may use: $("[data-input='" + response.field + "']").closest('.file-wrapper').find(".image_name").remove();

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain correct. I confused with these data attributes. I have multiple divs with the same input name of the field so I want to differ them using 1data-item`. I found this way to find input with this name and data-item. ` $("input[name^='" + response.field + "'][data-item='" + response.item + "']").parents('.file-wrapper').find(".image_name").remove();`

Comment: @mistery_girl I understood. Sorry again, but are you sure the parents is the right method instead of closest?

Answer (score 1):

This example illustrates how to use multiple selectors in JQuery to get element with more attributes:

```
<h1 name="director_front_passport" data-item="1">Text to be deleted after 3 seconds.</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function (){
        $("[name='director_front_passport'][data-item='1']").remove();
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: also remove [] from director_front_passport